# Transaction exceeded the individual limit of 0$

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk, recurring-billing

When I am trying to make payments to my Sandbox test store I keep getting this error. It was working fine a few days back.

[image]

Comment: Fix has been pushed. Run a test payment and share the result.

Comment: Still the exact same message. Tried with 2 different buyer logins.